# button stops working with position absolute React Native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

my button doesn't work when I set it to absolute position, when setting is to be on top of a carousel... I suppose it is getting under something because when removing the absolute it works normally, but I don't know how to solve it

Short code:

```
export default class SpaceDetail extends React.Component {

    state = {
        optionSelected: "Fotos",
        favorite: true,
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView indicatorStyle="black">
                <ContainerPhotoMap>
                    {this.state.optionSelected === "Fotos" ? <Carousel /> : <Maps />}
                </ContainerPhotoMap>

                <ButtonFavorite
                    onPress={() => {this.setState({favorite: !this.state.favorite})}}
                >
                    <MaterialIcons
                        name={this.state.favorite ? "favorite" : "favorite-border"}
                        size={40}
                        color="white"
                    />
                </ButtonFavorite>
           </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

Short Style Code:

```
export const ContainerPhotoMap = styled(View)`
    max-width: 200px;
`;

export const ButtonFavorite = styled(Button)`
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
`;
```

Short carousel code:

```
export default class Carousel extends React.Component {
    state = {
        active: 0,
    };

    change = ( {nativeEvent} : {nativeEvent:any} ) => {
        const slide = Math.ceil(
            nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width
        );
        if (slide !== this.state.active) {
            this.setState({ active: slide });
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ width, height }}>
                <ScrollView
                    pagingEnabled
                    scrollEnabled
                    horizontal
                    onScroll={this.change}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator
                    style={{ width, height }}
                >
                    {images.map((image, index) => (
                        <Image
                            key={index}
                            source={{ uri: image }}
                            style={{ width, height, resizeMode: "cover" }}
                        />
                    ))}
                </ScrollView>
                <View
                    style={{
                        flexDirection: "row",
                        position: "absolute",
                        bottom: 0,
                        alignSelf: "center",
                    }}
                >
                    {images.map((i, k) => (
                        <Text
                            key={k}
                            margin="3px"
                            color={k === this.state.active ? "white" : ""}
                        >
                            ⬤
                        </Text>
                    ))}
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Style Carousel:

```
export const ViewCarousel = styled(View)`
    width: width;
    height: height;
    position: relative;
`;
```

Button print on the right,
[image: img pointing the problem]

Comment: Have you tried adding a `z-index` property to the button?

Comment: I tried it now and it didn't work  ===========

export const ButtonFavorite = styled(Button)`
 z-index: 5;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
`;

Comment: Have you tried using `TouchableOpacity` instead of `Button` ?

Comment: What if you replace the ScrollView with a View (I know you need the ScrollView, but just for an experiment)? I have experienced that with ScrollViews and absolute positioned childs, I need to use the contentContainerStyle property of the ScrollView

Comment: thanks @masbossun, your idea with a few more settings worked!

Comment: scrollview to view switch had not taken effect Rasmus Knap, tks!